# Cannot find name 'grecaptcha'

Tags: angular, typescript

I've a form in angular 2 application.
Once the user submits the form, if some thing wrong in the user input then I'm showing validation messages.
Now the problem is I need to reset the reCAPTCHA widget. I can do that using **grecaptcha.reset()**. It is working fine.

```
disableSubmitButton(value) {
    grecaptcha.reset();
    this.isSubmitButtonEnabled = value; 
}
```

But in typescript file I'm getting a compiler **Cannot find name 'grecaptcha'** which is causing a build error.

How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: declare var grecaptcha: any; declare var at top before class

Answer (score 8):

Just encountered the same problem.

[This package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/grecaptcha) has the definition for grecaptcha

```
npm install --save @types/grecaptcha
```

Comment: How to import this on component?

Answer (score 1):

In **Nuxt 3** and **Vue** you would install the npm package and then add it to your tsconfig file. I guess Angular (or any project for that matter) should be similar.

```
npm install --save @types/grecaptcha
```

---

```
{
  // https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/typescript
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["@types/grecaptcha"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m using Angular 9.
I have installed grecaptcha as mentioned using this command:

```bash
npm install --save @types/grecaptcha
```

But also I had to declare it in the `component.ts` file above the class this way:

```js
declare const grecaptcha: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 14.

We have this in the `app.component.ts` right after our import:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    AdobeDC: any;
    grecaptcha: any;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
```